# Vuelidate date input

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I'm using vuelidate in my vue app. I want to set validation for date minDate for one week from now and maxDate for 3 months from now.

```
<label class="input__label" for="account_date">Ważne do:</label>
<input type="date"
       class="input__col"
       id="account_date"
       v-model="date"
       @input="$v.date.$touch"
       required>
```

-

```
date: {
    required,
    //minDate
},
```

I can't find anything about date in vuelidate docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no built-in validators for date in vuelidate:
https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-builtin-validators

Anyway, you can use JS lib like [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon) and create your [custom validator](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-simplest-example) to check dates.

Luxon has great documentation where you can find really helpful methods like [plus](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-plus) or [diff](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-diff) that can be handy in your case :)

Comment: Can I somehow achive it without this luxon lib? I don't really want to add entire lib just for one date input.

Comment: Sure, you can use vanilla JS to check dates and build vuelidate custom validator :)